# GRU input and training

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to train a RNN using GRU layer on multiple sequences of len N. How do I set up the input of the GRU layer and my train and validation data ?

I've tried different input_shape (like (None, N, 2), (N, 2), (None, 2)...), my data having 2 columns and a sequence being of size N.

```
def get_batch(train, ind):
    X = np.array([train.loc[i * N: (i+1) * N - 1][['col_1', 'col_2']].values for i in ind])
    Y = np.array([train.loc[i * N: (i+1) * N - 1][['target']].values for i in ind])
    return X,Y

model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNGRU(20, input_shape=(2, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(.4))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.5))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=adam(lr=0.005), loss="mae")

def cross_val(ind, train):
    fold_size = int(len(ind) / 5)
    for i in range(5):
        val_ind = ind[i * fold_size: (i+1) * fold_size]
        train_ind = [x for x in ind if x not in val_ind]
        X_train, Y_train = get_batch(train, train_ind)
        X_val, Y_val = get_batch(train, val_ind)
        model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))

cross_val(ind, train)
```

I end up with this kind of error:

```sh
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_54 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 4096, 1)
```

Comment: You can use a **Flatten()** after the **CuDNNGRU**

Comment: If I add a Flatten layer I can't even compile my model.

Comment: My bad, could you print **X_train.shape**, **Y_train.shape**, **X_val.shape**, **Y_val.shape** ?

Comment: Shapes are respectively (8, N, 2), (8, N, 1), (2, N, 2), (2, N, 2).

Comment: Is N your sequence size ?

Comment: If it is, GRUs expect an input of (sequence_dim, feature_dim), so you should reshape to get your **(8, N, 2)** into a **(N, 16)**, also in Keras, N has to be fixed during training. So you need to truncate/pad your sequences so they all have the same length.

Comment: Yes, N is my sequence size and it is for test and predictions.

I don't understand why I should reshape to (N, 16).

Comment: Maybe I need to explain a bit more.

2 is the number of feature for each timestep.
N is my sequence size, the number of timesteps in a sequence. For example, in a sequence of 1 min N would be 60.
And 8 is the number of sequence I'd like to train on.

Comment: what do you mean **8 is the number of sequence I'd like to train on** is it your **batch_size** ?

Comment: I have 10 sequences of N timesteps each. There is no link between 2 sequences. From those 10 sequences I use 8 for training and 2 for testing. I'd like to train on those 8 independent sequences. Is there a way to do that or should I train on one sequence at a time ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it, your model needs to be:

```py
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed

model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNGRU(20, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(2, 1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(.4)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(20, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(.5)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
```

As you have one ouput per timestep, you want to return a sequence

Comment: With that I can compile the model but I can't train it. The error is about the input shape being (N,2) while it is expected to be (2, 1)

Comment: You mentionned ealier that the shape of y was a sequence  (8, N, 1) ?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried some things and I managed to train my model but only on one sequence at a time.

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(CuDNNGRU(20, input_shape=(2, 1)))
    model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(optimizer=adam(lr=0.005), loss="mae")
    return model

def cross_val(ind, train):
    fold_size = int(len(ind) / 5)
    for i in range(5):
        model = create_model()
        val_ind = ind[i * fold_size: (i+1) * fold_size]
        train_ind = [x for x in ind if x not in val_ind]
        X_train, Y_train = get_batch(train, train_ind)
        X_val, Y_val = get_batch(train, val_ind)
        for j in range(len(X_train)):
            model.fit(X_train[j], Y_train[j], validation_data=(X_val[0], Y_val[0]))

cross_val(ind, train)
```

My question is, can I remove the `for j in ...` loop ?